# Continuity in topology. An example from Nakahara's book

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometric-topology

In his book "[Geometry, Topology, and Physics](https://cds.cern.ch/record/640926/files/0750306068_TOC.pdf)", M. Nakahara illustrates the topological definition of continuity with the following example:

[image]

I am having problems with this example.

Evidently,
$$
f:~~ (\,-\,1/4,~0\,]\,\longrightarrow\,[\,1,~1+1/4)~~,
$$
wherefrom
$$
f^{-1}:~~[\,1,~1+1/4)\,\longrightarrow\, (\,-\,1/4,~0\,]~~.
$$

At the same time, it is pointless to seek $f^{-1}(~(1-1/4\,,~1+1/4)~)$. Indeed, $(1-1/4\,,~1+1/4)$ is not part of $\,$Im$\,f$, and therefore $f^{-1}$ is not defined on $(1-1/4\,,~1+1/4)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the notion of an inverse function and the inverse image of a function. If $f: A\to B$ is a function and $C\subseteq B$ we define $f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A : f(a)\in C\}$.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite Yes. This is exactly what I was having in mind when writing 
$f^{-1}:~[\,1,~1+1/4)\,\longrightarrow\, (\,-\,1/4,~0\,]~$. This coincides with what you said, does it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the pullback is defined for points outside the image (whereas the inverse--when it exists--is not). 
To see this, if $y\notin Im(f)$, then:
$$f^{-1}(y) := \big\{x\in dom(f)\text{ }\big|\text{ }f(x) = y\big\} = \emptyset.$$
Couple this with the fact that for every subset $S$, we have:
$$f^{-1}(S) = \bigcup\limits_{y\in S}f^{-1}(y)$$
and we get  $f^{-1}(S) = f^{-1}(S\cap Im(f))\cup f^{-1}(S\cap Im(f)^c) = f^{-1}(S\cap Im(f))\cup \emptyset = f^{-1}(S\cap Im(f))$.
Thus in the problem, $f$ pullsback an open set $S:= (1-1/4,1+1/4)$ to a non-open set $[1,1+1/4)$ and so is not continuous.

---

Alternatively, using the *restricted topology* on the $Im(f)$, we can ignore the points outside the image. Note that:
$$(1-1/4,1+1/4)\cap Im(f) = [1,1+1/4)$$
is *relatively open* and its preimage is $(-1/4,0]$, which again is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the original topology.

---

To clarify, as per request, a function has an inverse defined over its image if it is 1-1. In this case, the point-wise pullbacks are all singletons (i.e. $f^{-1}(y)= \{x\}\equiv x$). The inverse image is just the image of the inverse.

Comment: So, to make this example work, we had to equip the two $\mathbb R$'s with different topologies: the domain $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, the range $\mathbb R$ with the induced (relative) one, right? It is not that this devaluates the example in my eyes, but it makes it less convincing... What if we insisted to keep both topologies usual? Would we not be able to define the map $F$?

Comment: So the function $f^{-1}$ pulls back an open set $(1-1/4,1+1/4)$ to a non-open set $[1,1+1/4)$, and therefore is not continuous. Is that right?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the recent discussion.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Reading your updated answer.

Comment: In your answer, could you please also define clearly the difference between *pullback* and *inverse image* and *inverse function*? In calculus, the notions of *inverse image* and *inverse function* seem to be clear (and it is also clear that the inverse function does not always exist). It still would be helpful to spell out these three entities' definitions in topology.